# Update an array in document in mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, backend

The schema below:

```
const questionSchema = new Schema({
    askedBy: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    title:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    queryType: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    question:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    datePosted: String,
    isOpen: Boolean,
    answers:{
        type:Array
    }
})
```

The code below:

```
app.patch("/:id" , (req,res) =>{
        
       Question.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {answer:[req.body.answer]}, {new:true})
         .then((response) => res.json(response))
         .catch((err) => res.json(err));

    
} )
```

What I want to do is take the answer string that is coming from the body and use it to update the array.
And the next time I do this I want that element to be appended to the array.

Comment: User `$push` operator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#append-a-value-to-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Question.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
   $push: {
       answer: req.body.answer
   }, {new:true})
.then((response) => res.json(response))
.catch((err) => res.json(err));
```